# how to get a random set of records from an index with cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

what's the syntax to get random records from a specific node_auto_index using cypher?

I suppose there is this example

```
START x=node:node_auto_index("uname:*")  RETURN x SKIP somerandomNumber LIMIT 10;
```

Is there a better way that won't return a contiguous set?

Comment: What are you defining as random? You want it to return any X items?

Comment: Yes, a random set of 10 user nodes in this case.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the translation under the hood is, but I'd imagine that `START x=node:node_auto_index("uname:*")  RETURN x LIMIT 10;` would use an iterator underneath that wouldn't consume too many resources. As for specifying Random, I don't believe that is an option unless you read all of them and then just skip in the iteration or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no feature similar to SQL's Random() in neo4j.

you must either declare the random number in the `SKIP random` section before you use cypher (in case you are not querying directly from console and you use any upper language with neo4j) 
 - this will give a random section  of nodes continuously in a row
or you must retrieve all the nodes and than make your own random in your upper language across these nodes - this will give you a random set of ndoes.

or, to make a pseudorandom function in cypher, we can try smthing like this:

```
START x=node:node_auto_index("uname:*")
WITH x, length(x.uname) as len
WHERE Id(x)+len % 3 = 0
RETURN x LIMIT 10
```

or make a sophisticated WHERE part in this query based upon the total number of uname nodes, or the ordinary ascii value of uname param, for example

Comment: Yes, generating the random number and pass it in as a parameter is probably the best.